# C# query MongoDB using GroupBy

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

I have a mongodb object as following:

```
public class Form
{
    public string FormId { get; set; } 
    public boolean Status { get; set; } //Published or Draft
    public int Version { get; set; } //The version of the same forms.
}
```

For the same FormId, there could be different version number and different Status. Some example data such as:

```
{
  "FormId":"1",
  "Status":true,
  "Version":1
};
{
  "FormId":"1",
  "Status":true,
  "Version":2
};
{
  "FormId":"2",
  "Status":true,
  "Version":1
};
{
  "FormId":"2",
  "Status":true,
  "Version":2
};
{
  "FormId":"2",
  "Status":false,
  "Version":1
}
```

Now I want to get a list of forms that for the same FormId, the Status is true and the version number is the largest. So the query result should be:

```
{
  "FormId":"1",
  "Status":true,
  "Version":2
}
```

and

```
{
  "FormId":"2",
  "Status":true,
  "Version":2
}
```

I tried to write the query in C# using Lambda expression:

```
this.AsQueryable<Form>().Where(p=>p.Status == true)
            .GroupBy(item=>item.FormId)
            .Select(t=>t.OrderByDescending(c => c.Version).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

But I got error:

> Additional information: FirstOrDefault of type System.Linq.Enumerable is not supported in the expression tree {document}.OrderByDescending(c => c.Version).FirstOrDefault().

Does anyone know what is wrong with my code? By the way, how can I know what is supported or not supported in the expression tree?

**I found out that if I write the query as following it works, but I believe this is not a good approach.**

```
return this.AsQueryable<FormTemplateEntity>().Where(p=>p.Status == true).ToList()
            .GroupBy(item => item.FormId).ToList()
            .Select(t => t.OrderByDescending(c => c.Version).FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated my syntax and tested to be working.

```
this.Where(x => x.Status)
            .GroupBy(item => new { item.FormId, item.Status })
            .Select(x =>
                new Form
                {
                    FormId = x.First().FormId,
                    Status = x.First().Status,
                    Version = x.OrderByDescending(c => c.Version).First().Version
                }
            ).ToList();
```

Output:
[{"FormId":"1","Status":true,"Version":2},{"FormId":"2","Status":true,"Version":2}]

Actual Code used to test:

```
        var _json =
            "[{  \"FormId\":\"1\",  \"Status\":true,  \"Version\":1},{  \"FormId\":\"1\",  \"Status\":true,  \"Version\":2},{  \"FormId\":\"2\",  \"Status\":true,  \"Version\":1},{  \"FormId\":\"2\",  \"Status\":true,  \"Version\":2},{  \"FormId\":\"2\",  \"Status\":false,  \"Version\":1}]";
        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<Form> resultList = js.Deserialize<List<Form>>(_json);
        var groupedResult = resultList.Where(x => x.Status).GroupBy(item => new { item.FormId, item.Status })
            .Select(x =>
                new Form
                {
                    FormId = x.First().FormId,
                    Status = x.First().Status,
                    Version = x.OrderByDescending(c => c.Version).First().Version
                }
            ).ToList();
        var output = js.Serialize(groupedResult);
```

Comment: Not working. Yours cannot even pass the compiling. By the way, the object class actually has lots of other fields, for simplicity, I just listed 3 fields here. For your query, do you mean Where(x=>x.Status == true) .

Comment: Try it again. I updated my original post and tested it to be working. Both Where(x=>x.Status == true) and Where(x=>x.Status) is the same. Your Form class should have the Status as bool data type (not boolean).

Comment: I am getting the error "An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The method OrderByDescending is not supported in the expression tree: {document}.OrderByDescending(c => c.Version)."

Answer (score 1):

```
 public List<Form> GetFromDetails()
{
    var DB = new Database();
    var collection = DB.GetCollection<Form>();

    var query = new QueryBuilder<Form>();
    var queryLst = new List<IMongoQuery>();
    // {
    //  "FormId":"1",
    //  "Status":true,
    //  "Version":1
    //};
    //{
    //  "FormId":"1",
    //  "Status":true,
    //  "Version":2
    //};
    List<Form> finalResult = new List<Form>();


    finalResult = collection.FindAll().Where(x => x.Status == true).ToList(); // pasing id 1
    // {
    //  "FormId":"1",
    //  "Status":true,
    //  "Version":1
    //};
    //{
    //  "FormId":"1",
    //  "Status":true,
    //  "Version":2
    //};
    var finalResults = finalResult.Select(n => new Form
    {
        FormId = n.FormId,
        Status = n.Status,
        Version = finalResult.OrderByDescending(v => v.Version).First().Version
    });
    // {
    //  "FormId":"1",
    //  "Status":true,
    //  "Version":2
    //};
    //{
    //  "FormId":"1",
    //  "Status":true,
    //  "Version":2
    //};
    DB.Dispose();
    return finalResult;
}
```

Above Method will help and i'm done because i  myself made a demo its working

Comment: What I want is a list of forms that the form is published(status is true) and the version is largest of that form.

Comment: Okay so List of Form having all Status == true is the first requirement and then from the first requirement you want one object with the largest Version number ?

Comment: @user3293338 my given answer is correct . as you said you want List of data where Status == true && FormId == 1 this will return :

'{
  "FormId":"1",
  "Status":true,
  "Version":1
};
{
  "FormId":"1",
  "Status":true,
  "Version":2
};'

and after that OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).First() wiill return : {
  "FormId":"1",
  "Status":true,
  "Version":2
}

Comment: The result I want is {
  "FormId":"1",
  "Status":true,
  "Version":2
}  and {
  "FormId":"2",
  "Status":true,
  "Version":2
} . You can check my questions again...

Comment: If you are using Where(x => x.Status == true && x.FormId == 1), how can you get a list of other FormId... I am not querying for a specific FormId, I want all the different FormId that with the highest version value...

Comment: Remove " && x.FormId == 1" from Where(x => x.Status == true && x.FormId == 1)

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me, but I could make it by using Sort before Group.

```
return _context.Products
                .Aggregate() 
                .Sort(Builders<Product>.Sort.Descending("InsertedDate"))
                .Group(x => x.Code, g => new {Code = g.Key, LastInsertedDate =  g.First().InsertedDate })
                .ToList();
```